# Solve the following differential equation: $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-y=2+5x$ in the mentioned method.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was reading a book called "Introductory course in Differential Equations " by D.A Murray.

A problem solving approach was presented in the book, which goes as follows:

> Solve $(D^3+3D^2+2D)y = x^2$

The solution given was :

> The roots of $f(D)$ are $0,-2, -1$; and hence the complementary function is $c_1 + c_2e^{-2x}+ c_3e^{-x}.$ The particular integral $$\frac{1}{D^3+3D^2+2D}x^2=\frac{1}{2D}(1+\frac 32D+\frac {D^2} {2})^{-1}(x^2)=\frac{1}{2D}(1+\frac 32D+\frac {7D^2} {4}+...)(x^2)=\frac{1}{2D}(x^2-3x+\frac 72)=\frac{x}{12}(2x^2-9x+21),$$ and $\frac 1D x$ being merely $\int xdx.$ The complete solution is $$y=c_1 + c_2e^{-2x}+ c_3e^{-x}+\frac{x}{12}(2x^2-9x+21).$$

Then, they asked to:

> Solve $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-y=2+5x$$ by this method ( method described above).

I tried solving it,like this:

> Given, $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-y=2+5x.$$ This implies $(D^2-1)y=2+5x.$ Now, we wish to calculate solution of the equation $(D^2-1)y=0,$ i.e the complementary function. The roots of the function $f(x)=x^2-1=0,$ is $x=\pm 1.$ So, the complementary function is $c_1e^{1}+c_2e^{-1}.$ Now, we proceed to calculate the particular integral of $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-y=2+5x.$$ This is given by $y=\frac{1}{D^2-1}(2+5x).$ We can write this as $$y=\frac{1}{D^2-1}(2+5x)\implies \frac{1}{D}(D-\frac 1D)^{-1}(2+5x)=\frac 1D(1+D-\frac 1D-1)^{-1}(2+5x)=\frac 1D[1-(D-\frac 1D-1)+(D-\frac 1D-1)^2](2+5x)=\frac 1D(1-D+\frac 1D+1+D^2+\frac{1}{D^2}+1-2-2D+2\frac 1D)(2+5x)=\frac 1D[(2+5x)-D(2+5x)+\frac 1D(...$$

But the problem lies here. I dont have to worry about the terms of the form  $D^n$ where $n\geq 2$ as then $D^n(2+5x)=0$ but the problem lies for the terms of the form $\frac{1}{D^n},n\in\Bbb Z,$ in the infinite series. How should I go on evaluating  this? I am not quite getting it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original problem, the inverse differential operator is $(D^3+3D^2+2D)^{-1}$. Before a series solution can be applied, it's easiest to factor out a $2D$ in order to get a constant term of $1$. But in this problem, there's already a constant term. So we only need to factor out the $-1$:
$$
y = (D^2-1)^{-1}(2x+5) = -(1 + D^2 + D^4 + ...)(2x + 5) = -2x - 5
$$

Answer (score 1):

Just for an alternative!

\begin{align*}
y''-y&=2+5x\\
y''&=y+2+5x\\
(y+2+5x)''&=y+2+5x\\
z''&=z\\
z&=C_1 e^x + C_2 e^{-x}\\
y&=C_1 e^x + C_2 e^{-x} -2-5x.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Since $2+5x$ is a linear polynomial, it's second order derivative is 0.

So it's easy to guess particular integral.

$y_p=-2-5x$

$y_p''-y_p=2+5x$